Create a list with SORTING and FILTER function with multiple criteria in a range




A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P




1




2024
2024
2025
2025



RowCrit1
RowCrit2

ColCrit1
ColCrit2


2




HY1
HY2
HY1
HY2



2025
HY1

MUC
A321


3














FRA
B717


4
Flight A

MUC

500
70
60
80

A321








5
Flight B

MAD

100
47
300
100

A380








6
Flight C

FRA

800
21
200
360

B717




Results



7
Flight D

MAD

90
56
150
578

A321




Flight C



8
Flight E

PAR

45
700
790
800

A220




Flight A



9
Flight F

FRA

600
150
40
10

B717




Flight F



10
Flight G

MAD

900
90
980
453

B757










In Cell O7 I want to display a descending list of the data in Column A based on the numbers in Range E4:H10 and the multiple criteria in L2, M2 and O2:O4 and P2:P4.
So far I have been able to develop this formula:
=SORT(LET(
    a, COUNTIF(O2:O4, C4:C10) + AND(O2:O4 = ""),
    b, COUNTIF(P2:P4, J4:J10) + AND(P2:P4 = ""),
    FILTER(FILTER(E4:H10, (E1:H1 = L2) * (E2:H2 = M2), ""), a * b, "")
),,-1)

It gives me the following result:




A
..
O
P




1






:






:






7


Results



8


200



9


60



10


41




This results is already correct from the numbers and the sorting. 

However, how do I have to modify the formula so it displays the flights from Column A and not the numbers?


Formula in O7:
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(A4:A10,FILTER(E4:H10,(E1:H1=L2)*(E2:H2=M2))),COUNTIF(O2:O3,C4:C10)*COUNTIF(P2:P3,J4:J10)),2,-1),,1)


Almost similar =TAKE(SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(A4:H10,1,XMATCH(L2&M2,A1:H1&A2:H2)),COUNTIF(O2:O5,C4:C10)*COUNTIF(P2:P5,J4:J10),""),2,-1),,1)


Formula in O7 is
=LET(col,MATCH(1,MATCH(E1:H1,L2,0)*MATCH(E2:H2,M2,0),0),INDEX(A4:A10,MATCH(SORT(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(E4:H10,ISNUMBER(MATCH(C4:C10,O2:O3,0)*MATCH(J4:J10,P2:P3,0))),col),,-1),CHOOSECOLS(E4:H10,col),0)))


If you have Excel 2021 (rather than MS365) =INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A4:H10,ISNUMBER(MATCH(C4:C10,O2:O3,0)*MATCH(J4:J10,P2:P3,0))),MATCH(L2&M2,A1:H1&A2:H2,0),-1),,1)

With SORTBY
=LAMBDA(
    col_to_filter,
    col_1,
    col_2,
    sort_by_cols,
    row_crit_1,
    row_crit_2,
    col_crit_1,
    col_crit_2,
    LET(
        include_rows, COUNTIFS(
            col_crit_1, col_1,
            col_crit_2, col_2
        ),
        filtered, FILTER(col_to_filter, include_rows),
        sort_col_index, XMATCH(
            row_crit_1 & row_crit_2,
            INDEX(sort_by_cols, 1, ) &
                INDEX(sort_by_cols, 2, ),
            0
        ),
        sort_by_col, FILTER(
            DROP(INDEX(sort_by_cols, , sort_col_index), 3),
            include_rows
        ),
        result, SORTBY(filtered, sort_by_col, -1),
        IFERROR(result, "No results")
    )
)(A4:A10, C4:C10, I4:I10, E1:H10, L2, M2, N2:N3, O2:O3)


